# How to reuse pseudo-terminal slave?

Tags: c, linux, tty, pty

I am using pty pseudo terminal to simulate serial port connection for testing.  I open the master:

```
fd = open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR);
grantpt(fd);
unlockpt(fd);
printf("Slave pty: %s\n", ptsname(fd));
```

That works fine and creates a /dev/pts/XX slave device.  My test program opens this device and works fine.  Doing a select() on this fd will block until a client opens the slave device.  However, when the client closes the slave side, the master goes into a loop of infinite 0 length reads.  How do I reset the slave device and go back to blocking until a client opens it, instead of repeatedly reading 0 bytes?  The only way I've found is to completely close the master side and redo the open/grantpt/unlockpt but then I may get a different slave device name?  I'd like to keep the same slave device..

Comment: `read` returning 0 indicates end-of-file.

Comment: Right.  In this case indicating that the slave closed their side.  But then a second read also returns 0 bytes instead of blocking waiting for a second slave.  So the question is, after the first 0-byte read, how do I reset the pt so that the second read will block until another process opens the pt?

Comment: @Aaron, you don't. While this may sound wasteful, the fact is, there is a surprising amount of *state* in a pseudoterminal, a lot of which is under the slave's control. The only truly safe way to handle different clients is to close the master end too when the slave closes; and, instead of trying to reuse the pseudoterminal, close and discard it, and just get another. The kernel will do a perfectly good job at recycling the resources; duplicating that effort in userspace is not a good idea.

Comment: It's not the wasted resources that I'm worried about, it's just a pain that the slave /dev/pts/xx device may change every time a slave disconnects.  I'm trying to use it to emulate a serial port, but serial port names don't change every time you use them..  I suppose I'll have to set up and manage a symlink.

Comment: I know it's 2 years later but I had the same issue. However I can do what I do with pipes, open it myself. So I just open the result from ptsname and leave it open. Now when the slave closes, nothing happens.